# How can I get the effects of a shared_ptr without using one?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, kernel-extension

I have a list which I implement using a struct containing a `shared_ptr` to the parent struct and a value.  I have a `find(char* path)` function, which splits the path into folders, finds the correct value for a given folder, then recurses to the next folder level, in the end returning the Node that can be followed to the root using the `shared_ptr<Node>` Parent pointers.

This works fine on Windows, but on Mac the code is being used in a kernel extension, and apparently a lot of the standard libraries (`string`, `vector`, `shared_ptr`, etc...) are not available for kernel extensions.  I was trying to avoid having the caller manage the memory of the `find()` function, but is that my policy choice?  To use `new(Node)`, then hope that all my callers call `delete` at the right time?
Rough code is here:

```
typedef struct ManifestRecord_t
{
    int value;

    bool FindChild(
      __in  char*target,
      __out const ManifestRecord_t *& child) const;

} ManifestRecord;
struct Node {
 const ManifestRecord* Record;
 std::shared_ptr<PolicySearchCursor> Parent;
};

Node FindNode(
    __in  Node const& cursor,
    __in  char* absolutePath)
{
    const ManifestRecord *childRecord = NULL;

    bool childFound = cursor.Record->FindChild(absolutePath, /*out*/ childRecord);
    if (!childFound || childRecord == NULL)
    {
        return Node(cursor.Record, cursor.Parent);
    }

    return FindNode(Node(childRecord, std::make_shared<PolicySearchCursor>(cursor)), remainder);
}
```

Comment: first things first show us your code?

Comment: Show some real code and data structure declarations.  I can't follow along with what you are describing to understand the problem.

Comment: I haven't done any Mac kernel extensions but both Windows driver code and Linux kernel modules have access to the kernel's data structures, which should include anything you need. Your code is NOT fancier than kernel expert's code, heh.

Comment: Is `unique_ptr` available?  If not, you can always roll your own smart-pointer class, it's not difficult to implement either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` style semantics.

Comment: Your question is focused on your particular code. It might be better if you step back and think more abstractly about your situation. What are your functional requirements? (E.g. a function that returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory?) Why a shared pointer instead of a unique pointer? (E.g. the memory is used by another object, but you want the caller to be able to keep it alive?) Mentioning "struct", "parent struct", the name of your function, and the specific functionality of your function might become a mere footnote.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code, I added it.  The reason why I want to keep track of the parent is to recurse upwards throw the result to find the lowest level Node which has value set to a specified value.

Comment: Your code won't compile - what is `remainder`?  What is a PolicySearchCursor?  What we really need is a [mcve].  Without it, I suspect you really just want to implement a linked list.

Comment: What do you mean by "recurse upwards throw"? There is no exception handling in macOS kernel extensions, therefore no throw/catch.